# Powershell Comparing two folders then copying it into another file

Tags: shell, powershell

I'm trying to compare two folders and copy the the files that exists in one but not the other into a whole separate folder.

This is what I have so far

```
$fso = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\Users\akalkandelen\Desktop\old

$fsoBU = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\Users\akalkandelen\Desktop\new



foreach($item in Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $fso -DifferenceObject $fsoBU -PassThru){
    Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination C:\Users\akalkandelen\Desktop\release 
}
```

The problem is that directory structure of the files copied into Release has to match. So if a file within a folder within another folder it has to maintain that structure. If i use -Recurse than it adds all the sub-folders and files into the root folder as well.

Comment: Use `robocopy`.

Comment: Could you be more specific on how to use Robocopy on this?

Comment: Type `robocopy /?` at the PowerShell prompt for instructions. You can also look up the `robocopy` documentation on the web.

Comment: take a look at this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/167723/robocopy-how-to-move-the-content-of-a-directory-but-keep-the-directory. It might put you on the right path with robocopy